# Xamarin.Forms: is possible to create a Button containing both a Text and and an icon fonts as Image?

Tags: image, button, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, icon-fonts

I tried to create a button that looks like this:

[image: screenshot: button with icon]

But, I would like to use a icon fonts (like FontAwesome) instead of a Bitmap as source of the Image.

I thought that I could it with [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize), but it's not the case: IconizeButton only replace the Text by the FontIcon.

***So is there a way to manage both label in Text and FontIcon in Image for a Button?***

Comment: You could give my library a try: https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton

Answer (score 1):

I did this workaround

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button  Text="Sign in"  Clicked="LoginHandle_Tapped" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="SFUIDisplay" FontSize="14"  BorderRadius="18" HeightRequest="36" BorderWidth="0" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#FF0067"/>
    <Label Text="navigate_next" FontFamily="Material Icons" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="None" TextColor="#FFFFFFFF"  HeightRequest="36" Margin="-30,10,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - purple icon to the left of white button text - all inside the button.
[image]

```
<Button Margin="0,10,0,0" StyleClass="Button" Text="ABC"
                    Command="{Binding OpenWebCommand}"
                    TextColor="White">
                <Button.ImageSource>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular"
                             Color="Purple"
                             Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.ThumbsUp}"/>
                </Button.ImageSource>

            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a View with a Grid (1 row and 2 columns).
In column 1 you add the Iconize control (with  a tapgesture). In Column 2 you add a Label (with a tapGesture). It should works

Comment: But how do you implement the View? As a new Control or as a Control inheriting from Button? Cause it's not possible to add Content to the Button...

Comment: The downside of using TapGesture is it no longer has clicked effect.

Comment: So there is no proper solution? It would be fine to create a Converter, to convert the selected Font Icon into an Image Source...

Comment: There is a "View" control that can contain a Grid. Otherwise use directly the Grid control. Yes, there isn't a "click effect" but I think you can try to recreate it changing background color